# Why we need to put space before %c?

Tags: c, character

The following code gives the bizarre o/p as soon as I compile it.

```
main() {
    char name[3];
    float price[3];
    int pages[3], i;

    printf ( "\nEnter names, prices and no. of pages of 3 books\n" ) ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
        scanf ("%c %f %d", &name[i], &price[i], &pages[i] );

    printf ( "\nAnd this is what you entered\n" ) ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
        printf ( "%c %f %d\n", name[i], price[i], pages[i] );
}
```

But if we give the space in the scanf statement before %c, it gives proper o/p.

Can anyone please explain me why is it so?

**Update:-**

If I am providing the input like this-

```
F
123.45
56
J
134
67
K
145
98
```

then my question is why not we are giving space before %f and space before %d? Why we need to give space before %c only?

Comment: Which `"%c"` are you referring to?

Comment: And what's the proper output?  What's the output that the program is giving?

Comment: @JeffMercado, updated my question. I am talking about scanf statement.

Comment: Are your book names really only one character long?  (e.g. 'X')

Answer (score 17):

Adding the space to the format string enables `scanf` to consume the newline character from the input that happens everytime you press <kbd>return</kbd>. Without the space, `name[i]` will receive the char `'\n'`, and the *real* char is left to be misinterpreted by `%f`.

So, say your input is

```
a 1.0 2
b 3.0 4
c 5.0 6
```

The program sees it more like this:

```
a 1.0 2\nb 3.0 4\nc 5.0 6\n\377
```

That is, the line-breaks are actual characters in the file (and the \377 here indicates "end of file").

The first `scanf` will appear to work fine, consuming a char, a float, and an integer. But it leaves the input like this:

```
\nb 3.0 4\nc 5.0 6\n\377
```

So the second `scanf` will read the `'\n'` as its %c, unless you get rid of it first.

Adding the space to the format string instructs scanf to discard any whitespace characters (any of space `' '`, tab `'\t'`, or newline `'\n'`).

> A directive is one of the following:
>
> - A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.
> - ...
>
> from http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

---

This sort of problem arises whenever you use `scanf` with `%c` in a loop. Because, assuming *free-form* input, newlines can happen anywhere. So, it's common to try to avoid the whole issue by using a *two-tiered* approach. You read *lines* of input into a buffer (using `fgets`); chop-off the silly newline characters; then use `sscanf` instead of `scanf` to read from the buffer (string) instead of straight from the file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am still unable to understand this concept. Pardon my ignorance, I am new to C.

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Comment: Just to add to luser droog. The new line character will be stored in a buffer and scanf first sees the buffer and if the buffer is not empty it takes the input from the buffer. Otherwise it takes from the stdin. So inorder to flush the buffer we put space infront of %c in scanf.

Comment: How about if I am printing the input like this as I mentioned in my question?  I am pressing enter after each input so then why not we are giving space before %f and space before %d?

Comment: That's because %f and %d automatically skip whitespace (and, btw, you *do* have spaces in there: "%c %f %d"). %c is different because it reads a single character, so if there's a space or a newline it'll read that.

Answer (score 6):

**Incorrect input using %c**

Consider the following snippet of code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    char y;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%c", &y);
    printf("%d %c", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

**Behavior:**
When you run the above program, the first `scanf` is called which will wait for you to enter a decimal number. Say you enter 12 (That’s ASCII 1 and ASCII 2). Then you hit the `return` key to
signal the end of the input. Next the program will execute the second `scanf`, except you will notice that the program doesn't wait for you to input a character and instead goes right ahead to output 12 followed by a `\n`.

---

**Explanation:**
Why does that happen? Let’s look at the behavior of the program step-by-step. Initially there is nothing in the buffer. When the first `scanf()` is called, it has nothing to read, and so it waits. It keeps waiting until you type 1,2, then `return`. Now what is in the buffer are the character 1, the character 2, and the character `\n`. Remember that `\n` signifies the end of input, once all fields have been entered, but it is also stored in the buffer as an ASCII character. At this point `scanf` will read the largest decimal input from the buffer and convert that to an integer. In this example, it finds the string "12" and converts it to the decimal value twelve and puts it in `x`. Then `scanf` returns control back to the main function and returns the value 1, for being able to convert one entry successfully. In our example, we do not catch the return value of the `scanf` in a variable. For robust code, it is important to check the return value of `scanf()` to make sure that the user inputted the correct data.

---

What is now left in the buffer is `\n`. Next, the second `scanf` is called and it's expecting a character. Since the buffer already has the `\n` character in it, `scanf` sees that, takes it from the buffer, and puts it in y. That's why when you execute the `printf` afterwards, 12 and “enter” are printed to the screen.

---

**Solution:**
Moral of the story is, enter is a character like any other, and is inputted to the buffer, and consumed from the buffer by `%c` just like any other ASCII character. To fix this, try using this code instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    char y;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("\n%c", &y);    /* note the \n !! */
    printf("%d %c", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**How does this fix the problem?**

So you again type '1','2',`\n`. The first `scanf` reads '1' and '2', converts that to the decimal 12 and leaves the `\n` in the buffer. The next `scanf` now expects a `\n` at the beginning of the next input. It finds the `\n` in the buffer, reads it, and discards it. Now the buffer is empty and `scanf` is waiting on the user to input a character. Say the user inputs 'c', followed by the enter key. 'c' is now assigned to `y`, NOT "enter". Therefore `printf` will output "12 c" to the screen.

NOTE: there is again a `\n` sitting in the queue now. So if you need to do another scanf for a single character, you will have to "consume" that '\n' before taking another character in from the user.

**This is not an issue for any other format specifier, as they all ignore white spaces before
the input.**

Comment: Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless
the specification includes a **[, c, or n** specifier

Comment: Most of your answer is formatted as quotations. If you're quoting some source, I suggest crediting it; if not, just write plain text.