# Why does scanf function asks for an extra input?

Tags: c

```
**#include <stdio.h>  
#define SIZE 3  
void scanA(int array[SIZE][SIZE]);  // prototyping
int main()  
{  
    int myarray[SIZE][SIZE];  
    int i,j;    

    printf("Please enter the array: \n");  
    scanArray(myarray);  
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)  
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)  
        {  
            printf("%c",myarray[i][j]);         
        }  
    printf("\n");  
    return 0;  
}  
void scanA(int array[SIZE][SIZE])  // function defintion
{  
    int i;  
    int j;  
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)       // looping to scan
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)  
        {  
            scanf("%c\n ",&array[i][j]); 
        }  
}**
```

//The scanf in the scanA function asks for 10 chars although it is looped 9 times
    I want to know the reason and a solution.

Comment: don't type your code here, copy and paste it from your editor.

Comment: remove white-space after the `"%c"`.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28820181/2410359 is on the right track: `" %c"`.

Comment: "  %c" - This worked. But, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put a blank space before the `%c` (only when you read a char), cause sometimes `scanf` reads the enter as a char. (I'm not totally sure about it, but with me this solution works)

Sorry for my english, it isn't my main language :(

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your answer. But, is there a particular reason behind it? I want to know that.

Comment: You must add the blank space because when you enter the char and press enter scanf reads two chars:the char you insert and the enter

Comment: @PahanMadusha here is another explanation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079144/why-we-need-to-put-space-before-c