# Why does this loop with scanf always quit?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char quit = 'n';

  do{
    printf("Quit? (Y/N)");
    scanf("%c", &quit);
  }while(quit=='n' || quit=='N');
}
```

Why does my program quit after inputting anything?

Comment: you need to clear stdin buffer. give the space before %c. do like scanf(" %c", &quit);

Answer (score 7):

The `%c` format specifier accepts any character, including newlines.  So if you press `N`, then `scanf` reads that character first but the newline from pressing ENTER is still in the input buffer.  On the next loop iteration the newline character is read.  And because a newline is neither `n` or `N` the loop exits.

You need to add a space at the start of your format string.  That will absorb any leading whitespace, including newlines.

```
scanf(" %c", &quit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  char quit = 'n';

  do{
    printf("Quit? (Y/N)");
    scanf(" %c", &quit);
  }while(quit=='n' || quit=='N');
}
```

For more information read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079144/why-we-need-to-put-space-before-c)