# how to choose an operator and show it

Tags: c

I don't know what is wrong wiht my program, i tried to enter the numbers from keyboard and enter any operator and sort them like "a+b", but I don't know if it is correct so far, I don't have errors, but when I enter an operator it shows "You did not enter an opperator" it goes straight to the else, I don't know why. If you could please help me, thank you!

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int op;
    int var = '+';
    int var1= '-';
    int var2= '/';
    int var3= '*';
    printf("Choose your 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%i", &a);
    scanf("%i", &b);
    printf("Choose your operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    scanf("%i", &op);
    
    if(op == var || op == var1 || op == var2 || op == var3)
    {
        printf("The correct order is: %i, %i, %i", a, op, b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You did not enter an operator"); 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some test input, and its expected/actual output?

Comment: Maybe you should define your operator as a char and also read a char from stdin instead of an integer with %c. That might solve already some conversion errors.

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all it'd be better to declare your `op` variable as a `char` instead of `int` as you are trying to read a character from the keyboard and not an integer number. Indeed if your try to print out your `op` variable as it is in your code you'll find out that its value is 0.
After changing this you should also change all `%i` for that variable to `%c`. This though will give a problem when using `scanf()`, which is that it will look like it got skipped. This is because the `scanf()` will read the last `\n` from the user as the character and put it in your variable.
To fix this you just need to put a space before `%c` so that the `scanf()` will skip the first whitespace character and then read from the keyboard. You can find more detailed explanation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079227/10997438)
Anyway down here there's the working code.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char op;
    int var = '+';
    int var1 = '-';
    int var2 = '/';
    int var3 = '*';
    printf("Choose your 2 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Choose your operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    scanf(" %c", &op);

    if(op == var || op == var1 || op == var2 || op == var3)
    {
        printf("The correct order is: %i, %c, %i", a, op, b);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You did not enter an operator."); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```